# Getting a useful substring function

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to estimate the size of a proposed database. We have created Excel worksheets that contain the column name and data type. As per some instructions I have, I need to multiply the column size by the number of rows. The problem involves the column size. I have data types like VARCHAR2(15 BYTES) but I need to extract the 15 as a number. If I were doing this in SAS it would take about 10 seconds to write the code but I have no idea how to do this in Excel. I want to identify the location of '(' and then read the next word delimited by a space, NOT a specified string length. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

With data in cell **A1**, in another cell:

```
=--MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND("(",A1)+1)-(FIND("(",A1)+1))
```

[image]

It is equally easy in VBA:

```
Sub GetNum()
    Dim v As String, N As Long
    v = Range("A1").Value
    N = CLng(Split(Split(v, "(")(1), " ")(0))
    MsgBox N
End Sub
```